# New views loaded with Angular not loading at the top of the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using hash routing in Angular.js to navigate between my different HTML views. However between "page loads" the DOM is not automatically scrolling to the top of the new page.

If the user is 50% down one page and navigates to a page of similar length, the new page will load 50% down as well. This is forcing me to call

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

on each of my pages. I have just looked into Angular's $anchorScroll and it solves the problem too but it seems to me the default behaviour should be to scroll to the top of each new view. Have I done something stupid in my code or does everyone just have to use $anchorScroll for every view of their SPA?

Comment: Doesn't $anchorScroll work or what's the problem. Please clarify and share your (controller) code.

Comment: It does work, but does every person who ever makes a Single Page Application with Angular.js have to account for this behaviour? It seems like something they could include by default.

Comment: I think it depends of the need of the application. I can imagine that in some apps, this is not needed or relevant. If you want a generic solution, you could use a provider: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try $anchorScroll service.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the only way to account for it. Was just making sure.